# match and replace varying number of groups

Tags: regex

Example:  I want to search and replace the following

```
51h 04h 02h     
CAh
```

and obtain:

```
cmd 51h; addr 04h; data 02h;
cmd CAh;
```

This would match the first line

```
^([0-9A-F]{2}h)\t([0-9A-F]{2}h)\t([0-9A-F]{2}h)
```

and I can replace with

```
cmd $1; addr $2; data $3;
```

But of course the second line would not match.  Anyway to cover both lines with one regex?  I am using regex from sublime text 2.

Comment: Its not really hard to match, however code logic is needed on the replacement side, something like a  callback, or you can just use 2 expressions, each rescanning the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
^([0-9A-F]{2}h)\s+([0-9A-F]{2}h)\s+([0-9A-F]{2}h)\s+(\w+)
                                                 ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/31)

**Logic:** Since `\s` matches both horizontal and vertical space it will capture the next word group in the following line

Comment: Thanks. But it is not what I want. I want to replace the first match per line with certain string, and the (optional) 2nd match with another string..